# Sort a table on clicking the header of each column using jQuery without duplicating the entire table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Trying to sort the table by just duplicating the row and not the entire table. On click of the column header that column's data must be compared and sorted and the rows rearranged , but I don't know where i am going wrong.Here is my code.

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html lang="en">
            <head>
         <title>Table Sort</title>
         <meta charset="utf-8">
         <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
         <script        src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js">    </script>
       <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function() {
                    $('th').click(function() {
            var ColNo = parseInt($(this).index());
         var rows= $('tbody').children('tr');
         var TotRows = parseInt(rows.length);
         for (var i = TotRows-1; i >= 0; i--) {
          for (var j = TotRows-1; j > 0; j--) {
                 var jint = parseInt(j);
             var frstval = parseInt(rows[jint].getElementsByTagName("td")[ColNo].innerHTML);
             var scndval = parseInt(rows[jint - 1].getElementsByTagName("td")[ColNo].innerHTML);
           if (frstval < scndval) { 
                var a = frstval < scndval;
             alert(a);
                var sourceRow = $('tr').eq(jint);
             alert(sourceRow);
             var targetRow = $('tr').eq(jint-1);
             targetRow.after(sourceRow.clone());
             sourceRow.replaceWith(targetRow);
           }
          }
         }
         
                    });
                });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
     <table>
     <thead>
       <tr>
        <th>Employee Id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
       </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
       <tr>
        <td>11</td>
        <td>AAA</td>
        <td>28</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>22</td>
        <td>BBB</td>
        <td>29</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>33</td>
        <td>CCC</td>
        <td>21</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>44</td>
        <td>DDD</td>
        <td>24</td>
         </tr>
        </tbody>
         </table>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: i think you go for some jquery library. i.e. datatable.

Comment: Yes I have tried those, but I want to know how to do as I said above.

Answer (score 0):

Better if you use a dhtmlXgrid... It's easier to implement, and you can create a JSON object of the entire dataset that you want to fill in the table. Then, just parse the JSON object into the dhtmlXgrid. With dhtmlXgrid, sorting, column size, column drag and drop, row drag and drop, etc., all such activities can be made automatically.